# How can I load an object file with a scene in OpenSceneGraph using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, model, openscenegraph

I am new in osg. I have installed VisualStudio with all the plugins for OSG. I have alreay tried some examples.

Now I want to download a scene and navigate inside it.

Can anyone help me???

Thnx a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source code to the examples. They almost all load a model from the commandline argument, or from a fixed filename (look for osgDB::readNodeFile()) and set up a Viewer with a Manipulator to navigate around the scene.

Also, questions like this are much better suited for the osg users mailing list.

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumm questions, but is it possible to load an obj file with a whole scene directly in the osg? Or should I create it from the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

If you've downloaded the prebuilts, you just need to run osgviewer, or in Windows drag your model onto %OSG_ROOT%\bin\osgviewer.exe, and you should be able to use the mouse to manipulate the model.  Hit "h" in the osgviewer window to see the help screen, which shows you how to switch modes, etc.